# Reflection issue, mapping database to object java-android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, generics

Here I'm with this generic issue. I wanna achieve a method that will be able to select all itens in my android SQLite database, respecting the following restrictions.

- Should be generic;
- Should be easy to use;

And here I'm, let me show as far I could go:

```
public <T extends GenericnessFactory<T>> List<T> selectAll(T returningClass){
    List<T> objects = new ArrayList<T>();

    String name = returningClass.getClass().getSimpleName();
    Field[] fields = returningClass.getClass().getFields();
    String[] columns = new String[fields.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        columns[i] = fields[i].getName();
    }

    SQLiteDatabase readable = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = readable.query(name, columns, null,null, null, null, null);

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        T item = returningClass.generate();


    }

    c.close();
    return objects;
}
```

I'm considering the class name as table name and the fields as columns, **but now I got it tricky, because, once T is generic how can I bind my cursor into a generic type?**

Just for knowledge, here go my `GenericnessFactory` interface:

```
public interface GenericnessFactory<T> {

    public T generate();
}
```

Any solution will make me happy, but if you could explain I'll be very glad to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your columns are of type VARCHAR just call java.lang.Field.set() method passing the value for the column read by the cursor. If you want to read some other types I'm afraid you'll have to write an ugly type matching cascade to call setFloat() setDouble() etc.
It would also be a good idea to check that the target field is not final or static or transient or maybe private.

```
public <T extends GenericnessFactory<T>> List<T> selectAll(T returningClass){
    List<T> objects = new ArrayList<T>();
    String name = returningClass.getClass().getSimpleName();
    Field[] fields = returningClass.getClass().getFields();
    int fieldCount = fields.length;
    String[] columns = new String[fieldCount];
    HashMap<String,Field> fieldMap = new HashMap<String,Field>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
        Field fld = fields[i];
        int mods = fld.getModifiers();
        if (!Modifier.isFinal(mods) && ! Modifier.isTransient(mods) && !Modifier.isStatic(mods)) {
            columns[i] = fld.getName();
            fieldMap.put(columns[i], fld);
        }
    }

    SQLiteDatabase readable = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = readable.query(name, columns, null,null, null, null, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        T item = returningClass.generate();
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
            fieldMap.get(columns[i]).set(item, c.getString(i));
        }
    }

    c.close();
    return objects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Tomato library - its a java ORM that has no dependencies and is super tiny and way fast and super easy to use.

The URL is https://rpbarbati.github.io/Tomato